# R randomForest sanity check -- simple classification

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

### Problem solved -- programming error - It turned out to be an error in how I was handling the matrices in R. Thank you to Sycorax for her/his suggestion on how to go after it. Best - Don

I am using randomForest in R to identify which of two classes each event falls into.

Each event has 42 features.

As a sanity check, I hand the routine a data set with one copy of 1000 events in class 1 and a 2nd copy of the same events in class 2. I expect it to fail in some way but instead it classifies every single event correctly. It also shows reasonable "importance" values for each of the 42 features. It only lists those 42 feature variables in the "importance" list so it is not using the class value of each event to do the classification.

Here is additional information:
All of the events in class 1 are read in first; then the events in class 2 are read in. If I scramble the order of the events, classification accuracy goes to about 50% and variable importance equalizes. That is what I expect but the order shouldn't matter.

Why does the order of the events matter? I have checked carefully and the event class is assigned correctly to each event after they are read in.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks - Don

Don Krieger, Ph.D.; Research Scientist; University of Pittsburgh; dkrieger@alum.mit.edu

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of this behavior? We don't need 1000 instances of all 42 features. Can you produce it with 100 examples of 4 features, or something similarly compact? We also don't need real data -- randomized/fake data works fine.

Comment: Dear Sycorax - thanks very much for your suggestion. I followed it and ended up finding an error in how I was handling the matrices. It's now fixed. Thank you. Best - Don

Comment: Glad to hear that it’s fixed! Programming errors can be pernicious that way.